# Prevent bluring css background-images with webkit on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, webkit, mobile-webkit

I'am using pixel perfect icons (with a single color) for background-images of html document links, as example

```
a{
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    background-image:url(/assets/images/icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 50%;
}
```

On desktop webkit browser (Chrome) they are normally viewed. But on mobile webkit browsers (Chrome or Safari) they are blured a little.

Is there any correct way to prevent such bluring?

Comment: The phone is probably trying to "enlarge" the image due to a higher resolution and/or pixel density. I suspect if you increase the size of your image, the blurriness will go away.

Comment: Why dont you try an svg icon? thats how i solved my problem.

Comment: @AlfredAlfizoMosima I have no svg icons for my backgrounds

Comment: @Jmh2013 I'am using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`, that is why I think device must exactly draw backgrounds. Is not it?

Comment: Having that doesn't really matter in this case. Lets say the image is 100x100 and appears fine on desktop. On a phone that is 440px wide it would appear blurry because that phone has a high pixel density allowing it to have many more pixels across so lets say 1000px. The phone has 1000/440 = 2.27 pixels in each real pixel. This means the phone is trying to stretch that image to be 100 real pixels however due to the phones pixel density it has to fill more than twice that making the image that's displayed on the phone enlarged to be 227px. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Jmh2013 Thank you for clear answear. Can converting PNG to SVG solve a problem?

Comment: If you're able to get SVG versions of your image, that would solve your problem as well. You should just be aware that it's not fully supported in all browsers.